# InvalidClassException when opening a serialized object in java

Tags: serialization

Okay, so I have an Object of class Region that I want to save. I have made Region and all classes that are within a Region class implement Serializable. My save method works perfectly fine but then when I try to open the saved file with the following method:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Open a Region object with the given fileName.
 *
 * @param fileName
 * @return The desired Region object.
 */
public static Region openRegion(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName + ".txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object readObject = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

        if (readObject != null && readObject instanceof Region)
        {
            return (Region)readObject;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But then I get the following error: java.io.InvalidClassException: htm.model.Cell; no valid constructor
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)

The Cell object is a class within a Region object but it defintely has a constructor that works like the following: 
public Cell(Column column, int columnIndex)
    {
        super(column, columnIndex);
        this.predictionSteps = 0;
        this.predictingState = false;
        this.previousPredictingState = false;
        this.learningState = false;
        this.previousLearningState = false;
        this.listOfDistalSegments = new ArrayList(5);
    }

Sorry for the long question, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *nearest non-serializable base class* of Cell must have a public no-args constructor.